# How to access edit read write data folder for game files on Android 13

Tags: android-13

Hey I play a game on my Asus rog 6 I just wanted to edit and change a config file in the android/data/gamefile... It's a config file but android doesn't let me change or edit that is there a way to get around that please kindly help me it's just a simple config file and I don't want to root my phone for that

I tried all files explorers but nothing worked

Answer (score 2):

Samsung S20 Android 13.
I have found that NO 3rd party file managers work to access these files. I've tried Mixplorer (free and paid). It does not work. I've tried almost all of them. No luck.
The only file manager that can access and read/write/copy/delete items in these Android folders on Android 13 is the hidden system file manager, which can be easily accessed using the shortcut "Files" app (by Marc), a available in Google Play. (Helpful trick: on the file manager tap "new window" , then go to "recent files" screen and get the two windows to open in "split screen". You can then drag and drop (copy/paste) from one window to the other.

The only 3rd party app that does "kinda" work is FV Explorer. But it only works through some convoluted steps which just end up opening the hidden system file manager! Though conveniently it opens it already in a two pane, split screen window. In the end it's probably simpler and more direct to just use the Marc "Files" app to open the system file manager, then merge two windows in split screen if you want to.

I still use Solid Explorer for everything else, but use the system file manager (via Marc Files shortcut) if I need to edit things in the Android Data folder.

Answer (score 1):

install Mixplorer from Google Play and give the app all permissions on the settings app on the phone (settings->Apps & Notifications->Special app access->all file access + modify system settings and also on usage access. when you have done this you open the Mixplorer app and go into the settings on the app(upper right corner where there is 3 dots on top of each other) to "more settings" and check the "allow root" box. Close the app and start it again and will see all the main folders on your internal storage. In fact it is written on the top "Internal Storage". press on the folder called "Android" and then choose the folder called "Data", and then folders for each system and user app will show as a long list. Find the folder that's  the game you are wanting to access, AND THEN THE SCREEN WILL CHANGE SLIGHTLY AND THE VERY BOTTOM IT WILL SAY "ALLOW ACCESS TO THIS FOLDER?" PRESS YES, SND NOW YOU WILL HAVE ACCESS TO THE FILES!!!

Comment: bottom line: don't rent your phone, own it (and be root)!

Answer (score 1):

Use FV file explorer and Shizuku to access android/data and android/obb folder.
First download and setup Shizuku app.
Then download FV file explorer, give it access to Shizuku and then you can access, edit and delete the files of android/data and android/obb folder.

You can also use ZArchiver v1.0.9 or higher instead of FV file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I myself haven't tried "all" file explorers, but I did a few and they didn't work as expected.

File Manager by File Manager Plus did work though, and it can be used in free/ad mode as well, just be sure to follow the instruction prompts to set permissions, there are a few of them while browsing.

I was able to back up a save file but also restore it. Other explorers just allowed me to view/copy the files from but not to that game folder, rendering them useless.

Comment: What device / android version did it work on? I'm trying this on an Android 14 Pixel 7a, and can't get it to work.

Comment: Motorola / A13...